# How to ignore the parent "src" directory when transpiling using Babel watcher

Tags: webstorm, babeljs, file-watcher

My code has the directory structure:

```
project-root/
└── src/
    └── main.js
```

When I run the default Babel file watcher, the code is transpiled into a dist folder, *including* the src directory in it's path, like so:

```
project-root/
└── src/
    ├── main.js
    dist/
    └── src
        └── main.dist.js
```

What I want instead is for the src to be excluded from the path - in other words, for the transpiled code in src to be "unwrapped" and compiled straight into dist, like the following:

```
project-root/
└── src/
    ├── main.js
    dist/
    └── main.dist.js
```

Is it be possible to change the watcher config to achieve this? I can't figure it out! Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's the `--out-dir` Babel CLI option behavior - it recreates the source folder structure (relative to working dir) in the destination directory.

You have 2 options here:

- use `--out-file` instead
- set `src` as your working directory

Possible setup for the first option:

```
Arguments: $FilePathRelativeToProjectRoot$ --out-file dist/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.js --source-maps --presets env
Output paths to refresh: dist\$FileNameWithoutExtension$.js:dist\$FileNameWithoutExtension$.js.map
```

For the second:

```
Arguments: $FileDirPathFromParent(src)$$FileName$ --out-dir $ProjectFileDir$/dist --source-maps --presets env
Output paths to refresh: $ProjectFileDir$/dist/$FileDirPathFromParent(src)$FileNameWithoutExtension$.js:$ProjectFileDir$/dist/$FileDirPathFromParent(src)$FileNameWithoutExtension$.js.map
Working directory: $ContentRoot$\src
```